# Are PhDs from former Warsaw-pact countries recognized in North America?

Tags: phd

Is someone completes a Ph.D. from a former Warsaw-pact country, would her Ph.D. be recognized in North America as in the same status as a North Americal Ph.D. in case of academia related career?

Comment: Some of the finest universities in the world are in those countries. Certainly the ones with the longest academic traditions. My advisor (in US) studied at Charles in (what is now the) Czech Republic. His education was disrupted by wars and politics, but it was an excellent one.

Comment: The general answer is yes, but the process depends a lot on the type of job you're applying for. At a California community college, there are minimum qualifications set by state law, and foreign degrees have to be evaluated by an independent agency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recognized for what?

For hiring as an academic, the main things considered are the publications; so even with a Ph.D. from an unknown university, someone with great research can be hired easily.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, of course. Go into any American mathematics department's webpage and odds are that you will find an academic with a PhD from the USSR.

Edit: with regards to "status", it really depends what do you mean by it. Do they have same legal status? Yes. Are they valued the same? Most likely not depending on who makes the evaluation. American public (and surprisingly good portion of academics) seem to value "university rankings" a lot more than other people do. Non-American schools seem to fair much worse on these metrics compared with the American schools. As an example, current times higher education world ranking ranks.

- 104th University of Arizona
- 105th University of Bonn
- 125th University of Göttingen
- 189th Lomonosov Moscow State University

Now, I have seen much stronger mathematicians with PhDs from the last three compared to the first. I personally would value higher either one of the last three than the first.

P.S: Indian IITs don't make it to first 300. However, they seem to have incredible students. Perhaps because they admit incredible ones. Even than why would, say Harvard, be any different.

Comment: what about social science?

Comment: @user366312 sorry I am in mathematics. Barely have any idea with regards to physics and stuff let alone social sciences. I would recommend checking department pages and leading researchers.

Answer (score 2):

The Warsaw pact was dissolved almost 30 years ago. It had nothing to do with higher education and research (only collective defense). Its relevance to modern-day academia is close to zero.

The Warsaw pact included countries/regions as different as East Germany, Albania, or Azerbaidjan. There is absolutely no reason to believe that diplomas from these places would be treated uniformly, and indeed, they are not.

Comment: I don't think the OP suggested that they should be treated _uniformly_.

Comment: I'd disagree; most North Americans treat those places uniformly because they have no knowledge of them.

Comment: It could not include Azerbaidjan - there was no such country.